# Can I use new BSD licensed library/code in commercial closed source project?

Tags: licensing, commercial, bsd-license, closed-source

I've found a software library, licensed under the new BSD license.
I want to use in my closed source commercial project. Can I do it?

Comment: Read and understand the license terms. If you have legal questions, you should consult a lawyer.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Did you read the license? Because it's pretty short and I think easy to understand. Unless your lawyer tells you otherwise, I'd say that yes, you can use the code, but you have to put their notice & disclaimer in your documentation (about box, whatever).

Comment: You say `it's pretty short and I think easy to understand`, and right after you're not 100% sure with your answer: `Unless your lawyer tells you otherwise, I'd say ...`.

Comment: @kravemir: I am sure of my answer. However, I am neither a lawyer, nor am I you. It may well be that you are bound by some contract or circumstance that would make it impossible for you to use this code. That's stuff I can't possibly know, and therefore can't issue absolute statements about.

Comment: I see what you mean. But, I didn't ask, whether BSD license conflicts my contract. But, it's good to point at related things. So, you're 100% sure, that BSD library can be used commercially in a closed source project, if there aren't any limitations by contract associated with the project.

Answer (score 20):

Yes. You can use BSD-licensed projects in closed-source, commercial projects. You must include the original copyright and license.

From [WikiPedia's BSD License page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses#Commercial_license_compatibility):

> The BSD License allows proprietary use and allows the software released under the license to be incorporated into proprietary products. Works based on the material may be released under a proprietary license as closed source software, allowing usual commercial usages under.

Comment: Can the same be said for government use?

Comment: The BSD license allows it. An organisation (company, government agency etc. ) can have its own rules that disallow use of BSD. That’s their problem. If your boss disallows use of BSD libraries, for whatever wrong reasons, you can’t use BSD libraries.